# Visual Studio shows incorrect version warning for RestSharp, despite correct versions in packages.config

Tags: c#, visual-studio, build, .net-4.8

I'm working on a solution in Visual Studio that contains two projects. Both projects use the RestSharp library, and according to the NuGet Package Manager, both are using the same version (106.15.0).

However, Visual Studio is showing a warning that the projects are using different versions of RestSharp. I've confirmed that the packages.config files for both projects list the correct version.

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State   Details
Warning     Found conflicts between different versions of "RestSharp" that could not be resolved.
There was a conflict between "RestSharp, Version=106.15.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=598062e77f915f75" and "RestSharp, Version=110.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=598062e77f915f75".
    "RestSharp, Version=106.15.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=598062e77f915f75" was chosen because it was primary and "RestSharp, Version=110.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=598062e77f915f75" was not.
    References which depend on "RestSharp, Version=106.15.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=598062e77f915f75" [C:\..REDACTED..\packages\RestSharp.106.15.0\lib\net452\RestSharp.dll].
        C:\..REDACTED..\packages\RestSharp.106.15.0\lib\net452\RestSharp.dll
          Project file item includes which caused reference "C:\..REDACTED..\packages\RestSharp.106.15.0\lib\net452\RestSharp.dll".
            RestSharp, Version=106.15.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=598062e77f915f75, processorArchitecture=MSIL
    References which depend on or have been unified to "RestSharp, Version=110.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=598062e77f915f75" [].
        C:\..REDACTED..\..SUBPROJECT..\bin\Debug\..SUBPROJECT_DLL
          Project file item includes which caused reference "C:\..REDACTED..\..SUBPROJECT..\bin\Debug\..SUBPROJECT_DLL".
            C:\..REDACTED..\..SUBPROJECT..\bin\Debug\..SUBPROJECT_DLL
```

Here are the steps I've taken to troubleshoot this issue:

1. Cleaned and rebuilt the solution.
2. Manually deleted the bin and obj folders in both projects.
3. Checked the .csproj files for any lingering references to an old version of RestSharp (none were found).
4. Cleared the NuGet cache.
5. Restarted Visual Studio.

Despite these steps, the warning persists. To further investigate, I loaded the resulting DLLs from both projects into dotPeek. The inspection confirmed that both DLLs are indeed referencing RestSharp version 106.15.0.

While I understand this is a warning and could potentially be ignored since both versions are confirmed to be the same, I would prefer to resolve this to maintain a clean build.

Has anyone encountered a similar issue or does anyone have suggestions on additional steps I could take to resolve this warning?

Comment: Are there any bindig redirects in .config files?

Comment: I checked and there are none.

Comment: You could try to check the following steps. 1.Inspect Build Output: Review the build output in Visual Studio to see if there are any clues as to why it's selecting the different version. 
2.Temporarily remove the RestSharp package from both projects, clean and rebuild the solution, and then re-add the RestSharp package to both projects. 
3. Check if there are any other libraries in your projects that have dependencies on RestSharp. Even if your projects directly reference version 106.15.0, if there are transitive dependencies pulling in version 110.2.0, it can cause conflicts.

Comment: I did try removing RestSharp package from both projects and cleaning and rebuilding but that didn't work. I'll try to see if I can find any transitive dependencies. I did look at the output of the bin folder and all RestSharp.dll files I found in the Debug folder were only of 106.15.0. So if there are transitive dependencies, wouldn't it try to pull 110.2.0 into the bin on build?

Comment: During the build process, Visual Studio will resolve dependencies and copy required assemblies into the output directory (bin folder). If you have confirmed that there are no direct references to RestSharp version 110.2.0 in your projects, and all RestSharp.dll files found in the bin folder are of version 106.15.0, it is indeed strange that Visual Studio is still warning about conflicting versions. You could double-check the project files (.csproj) of both projects to see if there are any lingering references or configurations that might be causing the issue.